# App is crashing when trying to add dynamic button on runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to add button and label on run-time. When I run app and it get crashed everytime.

Here is the code

```
UIButton *btnDelete = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

btnDelete.frame = CGRectMake (lblName.frame.origin.x+lblName.frame.size.width+5, 2, 30, 30);

[btnDelete setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

btnDelete.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];

[view addSubview:btnDelete];
```

When I run this code first button added successfully and when I try to add another button app crashed and shows following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a985cf0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Which line did it crash on?  Set an exception breakpoint.  You have tried to access the `text` property of a button somewhere, but a `UIButton` doesn't have a `text` property.  The problem doesn't appear to be in this code.

Comment: @Paulw11 No I didn't accessed any property. It is same as above given code.

Comment: which ios sdk are you using ? ios 7.0+ ?

Comment: @RatulSharker Yes it is iOS 7.0+

Comment: Some code, somewhere, accessed attempted to access the `text` property of the button.  Set an exception breakpoint to get the stack trace and identify where; it isn't the code you have shown

Comment: above code is perfect you are doing wrong somewhere else ..

Comment: Can you edit code including second button code?

Comment: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect is deprected from iOS 7. So may that is concern.

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug and find the cause of a crash.